# How to pass headers in a GraphQL subscription request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, subscription, express-graphql

I am trying to pass custom headers in a GraphQL subscription request, but the headers don't seem to be included in the WebSocket message. I am using the @apollo/client library on the client-side and ApolloServer from 'apollo-server-express' on the server side.

```
const sub = await client.subscribe({
  query: MY_SUBSCRIPTION,
  variables: {
    // ... subscription variables
  },
  context: {
    headers: {
      'X-Auth-Token': 'my-auth-token',
    },
  },
});
```

And here's an example of how I'm trying to access the headers on the server-side:

```
const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    mySubscription: {
      subscribe: (_, args, context) => {
        console.log(context.connection.context.headers);
        // ... subscription logic
      },
    },
  },
};
```

However, the console.log statement in the server-side resolver always prints an empty object, indicating that the headers are not being passed in the WebSocket message.

I've tried researching this issue and have seen some suggestions to use the SubscriptionClient class from the subscriptions-transport-ws library, but I'd prefer to use the WebSocketLink class from @apollo/client if possible.

Any help with passing headers in a GraphQL subscription request using `@apollo/client` and `apollo-server-express` would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi did you ever find a way to get the headers?

Comment: @leo_cape No. Maybe you are not supposed to need headers in a subscription request. However, you can pass headers as additional args in the query. If you need them in the subscription handler